# Fetching Product from database by product ID and adding it to my cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I want to add an **input box** where *user can enter* **Product ID** besides a **AddtoCart button** clicking which the product will be *added to users Shopping Cart*. How to accomplish this?

Comment: I am using this in the button                      onclick="location.href ='{{config path="base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=n''"                                           where n is the value entered in the input box..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

accomplished by using jQuery.post()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/